Why is the data not displayed in django rest framework?
Good afternoon I ran into the problem that the data on the page with json is not displayed.
models
class Example (models.Model):
Text = models.TextField(null=True)
def __str__(self):
    return self.Text[0:50]

serializers
class ExampleSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model= Example
        fields='__all__'

View
class ExampleAPI(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset= Dictionary.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ExampleSerializer 

    def get_paginated_response(self, data):
       return Response(data)

url
routExample= routers.SimpleRouter()
routExample.register(r'ExampleAPI', views.ExampleAPI)

urlpatterns = [
    path("ExampleAPI/", include(routExample.urls)),
]

But the data is still not displayed

but they are present in admin

And even the linked model has data in json format


Is your example correct? Your view calls the incorrect model in the queryset.
